# Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 installation

Tags: sql-server-2008, business-intelligence

I'm feeling like a bit of a moron, but I can't find how to install Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008. I have 2005 currently, but need to upgrade for some features. I'm pretty sure that it's included with SQL Server 2008 Standard, but I guess I could be wrong. Is it included? and if so, where do I find the install for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's in the 'Shared Features' of the installation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143786.aspx

Comment: I had to uninstall sql server express in order for the option to install BIDS to be there in the installation process

Comment: I was able to avoid uninstalling my SQL Express installation by performing a new instance installation of Standard.

Answer (score 2):

yeah it's included with standard edition. Make sure you select the Business Intelligence development feature while installing it.