# Cannot open .rptproj files in VS2008/BIDS

Tags: sql-server-2008, business-intelligence, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a problem. This co-worker, whenever they open a BIDS project it gives her an error message:

> ...cannot be opened because its project type (.rptproj) is not
>   supported by this version of the application.

However, if I remote onto the computer using my login, it opens stuff just fine. The thing is, it was working for them for about 8-9 months. It just 'randomly' started doing this today. It also gives a similar error when creating new report projects.

Do you have an idea what the issue might be? I'm thinking maybe it's a configuration in the user profile? I mean, the computer obviously can open it up- just not for them. Has anyone experienced this and resolved it?

We are using the BIDS suite that comes with SQL Server. It is VS2008, we are running SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This message usually means that Visual Studio doesn't support the project, either because it doesn't or because the handler of this project is missing, perhaps a reinstall of the project handler (or Visual Studio) may help.

Answer (score 3):

From [Solved: project type (.rptproj) is not supported by this version of the application](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/junk/rptproj.html):

> Install "Business Intelligence Development Studio" from the SQL Server 2008 installer.

See [Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764825/business-intelligence-development-studio-2008-installation) for more information on the installation.